# What is the best technology for content display and ads in screens?

Tags: silverlight, qt, javafx

I would like to know what do you think in which is the best technology to do an content display interface (ads, weather, news) for screens.

What I've found is that QT, Silverlight and java FX could be an option. Is there a better one? I prefer open-source. (LGPL is fine too)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention it, but you might also want to consider **web technologies** (HTML5, Javascript). They are widely supported (by multiple vendors) and well standardized, so it should be a safe bet. It's also quite easy to hire competent people.

Flash is slowly dying so I wouldn't bet on it. Silverlight is basically only backed by Microsoft and its adoption doesn't seem great, so it looks like something Microsoft could decide to kill overnight. Its multi-platform support is also sub-par.

Qt is nice but I'm not sure if it's the best tool for what you want to do. I don't know JavaFX, so I won't comment.

Comment: this is not to be used by others, other people will only see content on it (it is not interactive). basically it will be an application that should run on system start that will show ads and rss news, weather etc on screens

Comment: I understand that, but I don't see what could prevent you to display a full screen browser? You can use any browser you like, you can use linux as the underlying OS so you don't have to pay license fees, and you're assured to use a supported technology that's here for a long time.

Comment: Plus updating content will be trivial since you're basically updating a website.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a widely used technology and a pretty cool graphics.

**Silverlight and Flash are on the edge of each other**, since if you depend on (even successful) other technologies they may not be popular enough, i.e. the users want everything easily and believe me for an end-user it is a tough task to install Adobe Flash Player or Silverlight run-time, here comes the popularity benefit, by using something that is dominant.

Comment: this is not to be used by others, other people will only see content on it (it is not interactive). basically it will be an application that should run on system start that will show ads and rss news, weather etc on screens